# How I can change display mode (grid/list) in React.js app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in React and I try to build my Movie app for training. I need to change view in my react.js app. It shows list of movie in the Home Page. Also I have Account page(another component) where user can change a display mode of movie list(Grid view or list view)

I created a state in App.js component(my Homepage with movielist) and function that changes value to opposite. In component Movies I pass the value of view through props. Also I pass these to Account component where I tracking changes by click on button

```
 const [moviesGridView, setMoviesGridView] = useState(true);
 const changeView = () => {
    setMoviesGridView(!moviesGridView);
  };

<Route
 path="/"
 element={ <Movies movies={popularMoviesList} gridView={moviesGridView} />}
/>

<Account
 moviesGridView={moviesGridView}
 setMoviesGridView={setMoviesGridView}
/>
```

In Movies component I checked the value of gridView and show the right component

```
export const Movies = ({ movies, gridView }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {gridView ? (
        <MoviesGrid movies={movies} />
      ) : (
        <MoviesList movies={movies} />
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

In Account component I track changes by click on the button

```
<button
 onClick={
  () => setMoviesGridView(!moviesGridView);
 }
>  Change Movies View
</button>
```

So when I click the button the state is changes but when I go to the HomePage it's showed grid view again withous changes. I need change view and keep it every time I click the button. I feel that I do something wrong but don't know what certain. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello intkei, welcome to Stackoverflow, if I understand your question correctly, It's seem you want a `moviesGridView` still have the same value when you switch a page. In order to make state live long enough between page you can either use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), or you can use [React Context](https://react.dev/reference/react/createContext) to make state live much longer than the `Movies` components when you switch page.

Comment: @UnknownRori thanks a lot. I'll read more about these things